# SELECT user who has some values

Tags: mysql

#### Data

```
name 'chan' value 'a'
name 'chan' value 'b'
name 'max' value 'a'
name 'max' value 'b'
name 'tony' value 'a'
name 'tony' value 'c'
```

I need to find out user who both have value `a` and `b`, this is my solution:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
GROUP BY `name`
HAVING SUM(IF(`value` = 'a', 1, 0)) >= 1 AND SUM(IF(`value` = 'b', 1, 0)) >= 1
```

Any better way?

Answer (score 5):

Your solution is ok, but it would be better written as:

```
SELECT name
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `name`
HAVING SUM(`value` = 'a') >= 1 AND SUM(`value` = 'b') >= 1;
```

A possibly more efficient form is:

```
SELECT name
FROM `table`
WHERE value in ('a', 'b')
GROUP BY `name`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value) = 2;
```

And, depending on your data structure and indexes and size, this could also be efficient:

```
select ta.name
from table ta join
     table tb
     on ta.name = tb.name and ta.value = 'a' and tb.value = 'b';
```

I prefer the methods using `group by` and `having` because they generalize to a more diverse set of conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. a `DISTINCT` is required if `name` per `value` in not unique. 

eg (`COUNT(DISTINCT value) = 2`)

```
SELECT name
FROM tableName
WHERE value IN ('a', 'b')
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```